# how to store a token in request headers and make another API call using that token in header in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, token, laravel-8, laravel-api

I'm fairly new to Laravel and I have to connect to an API service, first authenticate, get the token and then use that token to make other API calls.

I understand that I can use the HTTP client to do the initial authentication and get the token. Now I've got the token, how do I store it? Does it goes into the database or I store it in session and then how do I use that in my other API calls?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you are using SESSION, then may be you dont need to use token, you need to use token when call api example from Mobile side, you can store token in preferene in mobile, or for browser you can store in cookie or localstorage

Comment: I'm not using sessions for now. I just want to hit the API with credentials, get the token, and do further api calls using the token.

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `cookies`